# How to remove extra spaces in the middle of the string while adding using sql

Tags: jquery

How to disable the date from next days

```
<html lang="en">
```

jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality

$(function() {

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

});

Date:

Comment: And any pattern example of the string ?

Comment: If you can, do it in your application! MySQL is responsible for STORE the data, not to validate/clean it. And @AbhikChakraborty is right, without example, or any visible effort from sour side will led to a nice 'Unclear what you are asking' or 'Very Low Quality' flag, then deletion of the question. Please read [ask] in the [help] to learn the basics, how to ask in a Q&A site.

Comment: if iam adding abc def for the first time it is adding successfully but for the second time if i add abc   def also it is adding

Comment: Plz add some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)** function to remove the extra spaces

```
SELECT  REPLACE('xxxx     yyyyy wwww eee', ' ', '')
```

**Output:**

```
xxxxyyyyywwwweee
```